# Memory overflow in a timetable

Tags: optaplanner

I'm writing a school timetable in optaplanner, and if I change my constraints slightly, the memory use increases without bound (hundreds of gigs).

The following constraint works fine (memory use on 4 threads tops out at about 1g):

```
private Constraint teachingLoadConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory)
    {
    return constraintFactory
        .forEach(Lecture.class)
       .groupBy(Lecture::getInstructor, ConstraintCollectors.count())
       .filter((instructor, count)-> count>instructor.getTeachingLoad() )
        .penalize("Exceeds teaching load", HardSoftScore.ofHard(100), (instructor,count)->count-instructor.getTeachingLoad());
       
    }
```

However, if I add in a filter to only check those courses in the fall the memory usage increases without bound (eventually leading to an exception):

```
private Constraint teachingLoadConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory)
    {
    return constraintFactory
        .forEach(Lecture.class)
        .filter(Lecture::getIsFall)
       .groupBy(Lecture::getInstructor, ConstraintCollectors.count())
       .filter((instructor, count)-> count>instructor.getTeachingLoad() )
        .penalize("Exceeds teaching load", HardSoftScore.ofHard(100), (instructor,count)->count-instructor.getTeachingLoad());
       
    }
```

How should I implement this idea?  I've tried various things for that filter.  Right now, getIsFall is implemented as:

```
    @ProblemFactProperty
    public boolean getIsFall(){return isFall;}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the memory growth with the Course Timetabling example but I find it suspicious to see the `@ProblemFactProperty` on your `Lecture#getIsFall()` method. Read its Javadoc. It's meant to be used on the `@PlanningSolution` annotated class to add facts for constraint evaluation. `getIsFall()` is not a fact, it's just a property of the `Lecture` entity. Remove the annotation and see whether it has any impact on the memory consumption.

Comment: I don't see how this change could lead to such a memory increase. Could you use e.g. a VisualVM or a similar tool to analyze the heap when it happens and see what takes that amount of memory?

Comment: The @ProblemFactProperty is something I added in later in wild hopes of fixing something I didn't understand.  The memory leak happens either way.

Comment: As suggested above, I used VisualVM to get a heap dump (I'm new to all of this, so any feedback is welcome).  The class which is using up more memory than any other was org.drools.tms.agenda.TruthMaintenanceSystemRuleTerminalNodeLeftTuple (38%) followd by org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle (16%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have recently fixed a bug that had very similar, if not the same, symptoms. I suggest you wait for the release of OptaPlanner 8.23.0.Final, and let us know if the issue is still there.